# How can I view and play shared audio files through a network?

Tags: linux, networking, audio, nfs, media

I've come up with a quick pet project (which might, maybe, even end up being useful at my home someday); the idea is to allow users of a Linux device (I'll call it A, and it'll probably be a small embedded one) to play music that is stored in other computers (I'll designate those by B), located in the same local network. The difference between this and straight-out streaming would be that, in this case, B would be as passive as possible, merely making the files available, and A users would be able to view shared files and select a target for playback.

I haven't found ready-made solutions for this case, though I'm sure many of them are bound to exist. So my question is what would be the easiest way to do it: through a ready-made solution or, if one is not available, through combining various applications and standards (NFS?) or coding it out.

Comment: There are tons of already-built things which do this, pretty much *any* much player can play from a network share. There are even fairly cheap boxes you can buy and connect to a TV that will play music off of shares (of the appropriate type). Like, say, a PS3. Please be more specific, this is hopelessly lacking in focus...

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers_and_clients

Comment: You may or may not want to use a sound server: [Sending audio through network](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1893/sending-audio-through-network)

Comment: Since it was a pet project anyway, I really didn't have a very specific focus. But thanks everyone, I'll be looking into those media servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to streaming media and sharing files, you have several options. Some are more compatible with others. I would be interested in knowing what OS or application system B is. This might help:

```
Linux <-- SMB --> Windows
Linux <-- Netatalk (AFP) --> OS X
Linux <-- uPNP --> Most Media Servers regardless of Operating System
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use SMB ("Windows File Sharing") on both machines. B will share folders full of files, and A will browse those folders. There are numerous clients and a couple of SMB servers available for various distros and DEs.

Answer (score 0):

As for a *ready-made solution*, how about giving [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/) a try?  It would run on **B** and any **A** can use it to playback music stored on **B**, with the integrated media player or any [Ampache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampache)-[compatible media player](http://owncloud.org/media-player/) (Or you could just use Ampache, of course.)